# LWC lightning-tree-grid disable checkbox on parent rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I'm having a lot of trouble with lighting-tree-grid. You can't disable any checkboxes rows or hide grid-lines or hide columns. Salesforce support says "there's an open work item on lighting-tree-grid". I've been struggling to find a way to prevent users from clicking on a top level row and here's what I came up with.

I gather the parent rows into a "groups" array and then when the user clicks on a row that is a parent it never becomes selected.

I wouldn't call it a solution, but it does fix my problem. I'm open to any feedback.

component.html

```
<lightning-tree-grid 
            data={gridData}
            columns={gridColumns}
            key-field="id"
            expanded-rows={expandedRows}
            selected-rows={selectedRows}
            is-loading={loading}
            onrowselection={handleRowSelection}>
        </lightning-tree-grid>
```

sampleData.js

```
export const gridColumns = [{
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'pageName',
            label: '',
            initialWidth: 300,
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'id',
            label: '',
            initialWidth:100
        }
    ];

export const gridData = [{"id":"1234567","pageName":"Group1","_children":[{"id":"123456","pageName":"Component 1"},{"id":"234567","pageName":"Component 2"}]},{"id":"345678","pageName":"Group2","_children":[{"id":"567891","pageName":"Component 3"}]},{"id":"678912","pageName":"Group3","_children":[{"id":"789123","pageName":"Component 4"}]}];

export const groupsArray = ['1234567','345678','678912'];
```

component.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {
    gridColumns,
    gridData,
    groupsArray
} from './sampleData';

export default class component extends LightningElement {
    // definition of columns for the tree grid
    gridColumns = gridColumns;

    // data provided to the tree grid
    gridData = gridData;

    expandedRows = groupsArray;    

    handleRowSelection(e) {
        var selectRows = this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree-grid').getSelectedRows();
        let tempArr = [];
        for (let r = 0; r < selectRows.length; r++) {
            if(!this.groupsArray.includes(selectRows[r].id)){
                const row = selectRows[r];
                tempArr.push(row.id);
            } 
        }
        this.selectedRows = tempArr;
    }    
}
```